# Question about standard errors of regressions/means

Tags: regression, sampling, econometrics, standard-error

I just had a question about standard errors of sampling statistics/estimators. Is for example, the standard error of a regression coefficient, a true population value, that is estimated? Should I think of it in the same way we estimate point estimates-i.e. there is a true population effect, and then we estimate it with the data?

Answer (score 0):

You are estimating an unknown conditional mean with regression. As you get more and more more data into your sample, the standard deviation of the calculated mean (aka the standard error) gets smaller, which corresponds to the uncertainty about the population mean shrinking.

In the population, the mean is a constant, and constants have no variance, so your vanishing standard error is tending to that limit as you gather more data.

Simulation is good way to convince yourself of this.